# Solve diffusion equation in a circle using fourier transforms

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation

Given an infinitely long cylinder with radius a, we want to model the diffusive transport of molecules represented by u(r,t) to the wall, where r is the radial component. Given
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}
$$
where $D$ is the diffusion constant. Initial/boundary conditions are $u(r,0)=u_0>1$ and $u(a,t)=1$.

Find $u(r,t)$ using fourier transforms.

I was given the hint to find the steady state solution first and then subtract it from the full solution to solve with fourier transforms for homogeneous boundary conditions, but I'm stuck.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense.  You initially trap the molecules inside(?) the cylinder at higher density ($u_0$) and there is nowhere for the molecules to go, but you are also demanding at the boundary to be much lower density ($1$) at all time?

Comment: This is the problem as it was posed to me. Would it make more sense if $u_0<1$? Perhaps it was a typo.